# RF - Chip Antenna Matching

Tags: rf, smith-chart

I've gotten a little bit into the weeds with RF and am attempting to tune a chip antenna for GNSS. I had test PCBs made according to the chip antennas integration guide/datasheet and have attempted solving for a suitable matching network but have so far failed.

My steps:

To calculate the matching network, I first took a board that had only the chip antenna soldered on, then soldered on 2 0Ω resistors in series to bypass the matching network and soldered a U.FL connector onto the the pad for the (not yet populated) LNA. To measure I used a LiteVNA that was calibrated for the port extension and made sure the antenna/PCB were in free space, away from any objects that could detune the antenna.

I exported the touchstone file, and imported it into Atyune and ended up with VSWR looking like this:

[image: VSWR-No Match]

I then used the Atyune auto-matching set for reflection optimization and got this:

[image: Simulated Matching Network]

I ordered the parts, soldered them on and am now measuring this as my VSWR:

[image: VSWR-Sim Match]

Obviously that is not great. Does anyone have any tips or ideas on what I could've done wrong? Thanks!

EDIT:

Adding on some additional details that have been asked for.

The chip antenna is an Ignion NN02-224. I used their Antenna Intelligence service to get a matching network that kind of worked to start with but also yielded similar results. They looked at the layout prior to manufacturing and gave it their OK.

This is the PCB layout:
[image: PCB Layout]

This is the matching network generated by the manufacturer/general schematic for the board:
[image: Ignion Matching Network]
For the initial unmatched measurements, Z1 and Z3 had 0Ω resistors soldered, and the other components were left not populated. The U.FL port was soldered at U1's input.

This is the performance of that matching network which is better than what Atyune calculated but still not usable:
[image: Ignion VSWR]

Additionally, these are the Smith charts related to each case:

Tried to add the Smith chart for the unmatched case but can only have 8 links.

Atyune calculated matching network
[image: Calculated matching network Smith]

Manufacturer calculated matching network
[image: Manufacturer matching network Smith]

Comment: Can you post schematics and board layout and stackup?

Comment: I don't know atyune, but the proposed solution seems to be very different from what the designer of the matching circuits from your documentation had in mind; you might fare better with no software or better software. Anyways, vswr is the less interesting measure than complex S-parameters, as that's what you're matching.

Comment: @Aaron Schematic/layout is added in the edit.  The physical stackup is just the default 4 layer JLC impedance controlled stackup.

Comment: @ConstantineA.B. I added the matching network that was created by the manufacturer and that performance in an update to the main post. What software/methods of tuning would you recommend?

Comment: Wow, that indeed looks like a tough one! Looking at the Smith chart for the vendor recommended matching network, we have a problem at the lowest frequencies.  Instinctively, I'd try a slightly larger C3,  but would be anxious how the increased parasitics might ruin my higher band's day

Comment: @ConstantineA.B. Thanks for the advice! I threw in a 4pF cap for Z3 and it looks like it ended up helping the higher band quite a bit, it's now under 2:1 VSWR, however that lower band is still struggling although a little improved (~3.5:1 VSWR). How did you instinctively know that adding a little capacitance on Z3 would help out (somewhat)? I understand the basics of the Smith chart and all that but that intuitive knowledge is always a tough one :)